# Probability of at least one of a random set of strings becoming an specific word?

Tags: probability

If we created a program to put n characters together into a string, to make a specific n-length string, for example "goodtest" (length: 8), and we, for example, create 1,000,000 random 8 length strings, what would be the chances of getting at least 1 "goodtest"?

*Note:there are 26 characters to choose from*

Comment: Should we assume that there are 26 characters to choose from? Or are we supposed to include symbols and numbers too?

Comment: Yeah sorry, let's assume 26 chars.

Comment: I've provided an answer based on the word "goodtest" and 1,000,000 randomly selected 8 character long strings. The answer can be modified for any choice of word, any number of strings, and any length of string. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it's crystal clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's consider the probability that one of the strings spells "goodtest". If we select one string arbitrarily then the probability that it spells out "goodtest" is $(\frac{1}{26})^8$ since the likelihood of selecting a particular letter is always $\frac{1}{26}$.

We then use this to find that the probability that one of the words is **not** "goodtest" is $1-(\frac{1}{26})^8$

And so, we can extend this to all of the 1 million words not being "goodtest" by working out $(1-(\frac{1}{26})^8)^{1,000,000}$

We can see that working out the probability that there is at least $1$ instance of the word "goodtest" could take us a while, however, we save a lot of time by realising that the probability of at least $1$ "goodtest" is equal to one minus the probability of no "goodtest" in any of them.

Finally, we use this to find out the probability that at least one of the words is "goodtest", we find $1-(1-(\frac{1}{26})^8)^{1,000,000}$ which is our final answer.

Therefore, by simplifying, the likelihood works out to be $0.0000047886$